# Arraylist issue ArrayListName.add(new ArrayListName(.......));

Tags: java, arraylist, addition

I Download a file that has an ArrayList called comments, and I have a basic knowledge about array, I know if you want to add something to an array you do.

```
comments.add(author, text, rating);
```

but i saw something else or new and could not understand it.

`comments.add(new Comment(author, text, rating));` <<<< this is new for me

so please guys what are the differences between them, as I searched but no benefit could not understand it.

Comment: Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively. Questions of the form "I downloaded some code, please explain it to me" are off-topic. This is not a tutorial or discussion site.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about basic understanding of Java and basic data structures. There are plentiful of resources online that does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array is different from ArrayList

From your question I think you have comments arraylist. There are multiple ways to create objects. In your code it is created added to list in one line.

```
    //Create a new comment
    Comment comment = new Comment(author, text, rating);

    //Add comment to comments arraylist
    comments.add(comment)  which is same as

    //Other way to add to list 
    comments.add(new Comment(author, text, rating));
```

Comment: Thanks, for the help i got it.